# Cannot change the definition of AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED

Tags: filters, wp-config, automatic-updates

I have several WordPress sites that I want to enable auto update. I installed Background Update Tester to verify that the updates were enabled correctly, but I get the following message:

> FAIL: The AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED constant is defined as true.

It was defined as true in `wp-config.php`, but after I removed the line, it's still saying that the constant is true. I also tried to define the constant as false to no avail.

I also tried to add this filter inside a plugin:

```
add_filter('automatic_updater_disabled', '__return_false');
```

But WordPress still thinks the constant is true.

I ran a case insensitive grep for `AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED` on my entire Wordpress directory with no results (except for `class-wp-automatic-updater.php`, which seems to check the definition).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Would you by any chance be on managed hosting?

Comment: I have the sites hosted on a VPS, but they were moved from a shared hosting site by GoDaddy. @TomJNowell

Comment: Sorry guys, I just figured out that it was PHP zend opcache that was preventing my configuration from changing. Is there a way to close this question?

Comment: You can write that down as an answer and mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates  for help? Several options in there to enable/disable updates according to your needs?

Comment: Yes, I defined AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED as false and WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE as true. I cannot get any auto updates at all because AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED is always set to true regardless of what's inside wp-config.

Comment: Perhaps another plugin, or your current theme, is overwriting your attempt to set that value. What happens if you change themes, or temporarily disable all plugins (easy way is to change the name of the 'plugins' folder) ... if that is possible for your site without a bit effect on users. (You can quickly change back to current theme; then quickly fix the plugins by renaming that folder back to 'plugin'. If you are quick, should only affect the site for a minute or two.)